# I get an 'AttributeError: shape' when trying to rotate an image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import, resize, and conditionally rotate an image with OpenCV but I'm running into some trouble. To bring in the image and resize it I use:

```
def draw_plane(self):
    # Import image for plane
    plane_path = 'planes/' + self.plane + '.jpg'
    plane = Image.open(plane_path)
    # Get image size
    bg_height = plane.size[1]
    bg_width = plane.size[0]
    # Resize and crop image
    if bg_height > bg_width:
        # Resize
        ratio = bg_width/bg_height
        img_width = self.p_width
        img_height = int(self.p_height/ratio)
        plane_resized = plane.resize((img_width,img_height))
        # Crop
        top = int((img_height-self.p_height)/2)
        bottom = int(((img_height-self.p_height)/2)+self.p_height)
        plane_cropped = plane_resized.crop((0,top,self.p_width,bottom))
        print('top:',top,'\nbottom:',bottom)
        self.plane_img = plane_cropped
    if bg_height < bg_width:
        # Resize
        ratio = bg_height/bg_width
        img_width = int(self.p_width/ratio)
        img_height = self.p_height
        plane_resized = plane.resize((img_width,img_height))
        # Crop
        left = int((img_width-self.p_width)/2)
        right = int(((img_width-self.p_width)/2)+self.p_width)
        plane_cropped = plane_resized.crop((left,0,right,self.p_height))
        self.plane_img = plane_cropped
    else:
        pass
```

If the name of an image being used as a frame for plane is in a list I call the following method and if the first item in a list of attributes for the final composition is "Polaroid" I want it to rotate plane.

```
 def adjust_plane(self):
        if a.attr[0] == 'polaroid':
            plane = self.plane_img
            height, width = plane.shape[:2] <----
            center = (width/2, height/2)
            rotate_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center=center, angle=-30, scale=1)
            rotated_plane = cv2.warpAffine(plane, rotate_matrix, (width, height))
            self.plane_img = rotated_plane
```

But when I run the code I get: "AttributeError: shape" on the line I noted in the code block. This is all taking place in the same class, including the conditional that triggers adjust_plane().

I admit that I am at a point in learning to program that I am just beginning to wrap my head around objects as a concept. Is there maybe some issue that this is no longer an image but is an "image object", if there is such a thing? Any help is appreciated, I've been chewing on this error for far too long.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but I see elsewhere in your code you are using the `size` attribute to get the image width/height, rather than `shape`...

Comment: If `plane` is a PIL Image, it doesn't have a shape attribute, use plane.size instead, just like the 3rd and 4th lines in the `draw_plane` function.

Comment: I have tried replacing shape with size like I did in the place you mentioned @Priyatham but then I get:
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Is a PIL image maybe just not compatible with getRotationMatrix2D?

Comment: Given that you use OpenCV, what's wrong with `cv2.imread`? Why do people willingly complicate their lives by pulling in yet another library that just duplicates existing functionality... Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue is that OpenCV and PIL images don't play well together. Someone else could better explain exactly why.

I brought in OpenCV to rotate the image because I thought PIL could not rotate an image by specific degree rather than just 90° steps, but I was wrong about that. The code below accomplishes what I wanted with the PIL library and I was able to do away with OpenCV.

```
plane.rotate(30, Image.NEAREST, expand = 1)
```